# Integral of $\int_{0}^{2{\pi}}(e^{-ixn}(e^{ix}-1)^{m})dx$

Tags: integration, statistics, convergence-divergence

Can any one help me calculate the following integral:
$$
    f(m,n)=\int_{0}^{2{\pi}} (e^{-ixn}(e^{ix}-1)^{m}) dx
$$
where $m$ and $n$ are constant, $i=\sqrt {-1}$.

I tried but still couldn't solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\sqrt{1}=1$. Do you mean $\sqrt{-1}$? Then please use $i$ instead of $j$.

Comment: My bad, Thanks.

Comment: Are $m$ and $n$ integers, naturals or any real number?

Comment: I am having trouble seeing this as a function of $x$, the computation will yield a constant value, or at best a relation involving $m$ and $n$.

Comment: m is an integer number but n is a natural number @TommasoSeneci

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will correct it. Thanks @Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a possible way
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i x m}(e^{ix}-1)^n dx &= \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i x m}\sum_{k=0}^n (e^{ix})^k(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} dx \\
&= \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{k=0}^n e^{ix(k-m)}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} dx \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{-i}{k-m}\right)e^{ix(k-m)} \Bigg |_0^{2 \pi}(-1)^{m-k}\binom{n}{k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{i}{k-m}\right)(1-e^{2 \pi i(k-m)})(-1)^{m-k}\binom{n}{k} 
\end{align}
Now, if this is helpful you can assess the values of this depending on how you treat $(k, m, n)$. Clearly, for example, $k \neq m$. Also, what happens when $k-m= s \in \mathbb{Z/\{0}\}$?.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for helping me. Do we still have the summation at the end ?

Comment: Yes we do, I have edited. Thanks